# How a String can be modified if String is not final

Tags: java, string, immutability

In String class, I see all instance variables are private.

I see methods to operate on String.

If final keyword is not there in String class, all other code remains as is, and we sub-class the String class, since variables are private they are not accessible outside the class, how can we modify the string object. Please let me know a specific method from the sub-class, which we can modify string object.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of something, but the long story short is that when you do `String bat = "cat";` followed by `bat = "brown" + cat`, the JVM actually creates a new string object behind the scenes in the second case.

Comment: Why do you think there is such a method?

Comment: What sub-class? `String` is, itself, `final`. That means you can't sub-class `String`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch OP said *If final keyword is not there in String class*.

Comment: It allows you to override methods like `toString()`, `length()`, `substring()`, etc, which could appear as mutations, and to provide mutator methods.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created. Also, String is a final class, so you can't extend it. If you want a collection of characters you can modify, use StringBuilder: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html